# Broken rospy code API docs?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospy code API docs seem to be broken right now. The "Code API" link on the wiki page for rospy goes to a directory with nothing useful in it. Unless I'm massively missing something and looking in the wrong place, can someone either fix this, or direct me to the correct place to report the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48554/broken-rospy-code-api-docs?/) by [Elizabeth C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3009/elizabeth-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem to be right. The docs are broken. Consider sending a mail on the ros-users mailing list in response to the recent wiki crawler update mail.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-21**:
It looks to have been fixed.